# Translation question: how does this sentence structure work?

Tags: translation

Original: Most people think of nerds as quiet, diffident people. In ordinary social situations they are — as quiet and diffident as the star quarterback would be if he found himself in the middle of a physics symposium.

大多數人認為書獃子是安靜和害羞的。
在通常的社交場合下，比如物理學研討會中，書獃子確實是那樣，就像橄欖球場上的四分衛一樣。

Source: https://xueqiu.com/6663886898/188768282

Breaking down the second sentence Chinese translation, it seems like:

在通常的社交場合下 - in ordinary social situations
比如物理學研討會中 - for example in a physics symposium
書獃子確實是那樣 - nerds really are like that
就像橄欖球場上的四分衛一樣 - just like a football quarterback

The ordering feels really weird, so I'm not sure if I didn't know the original English if I could derive the same meaning from the Chinese sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

大多數人認為書獃子是安靜和害羞的。在通常的社交場合下，比如物理學研討會中，書獃子確實是那樣，就像橄欖球場上的四分衛一樣。×

大多數人認為書獃子是安靜和害羞的。在通常的社交場合下，書獃子確實是那樣，就像置身於物理學研討會中的四分衛一樣。√